# Potential inside an insulating sphere integrating from $V_0 = 0$ vs. $V_{\infty} = 0$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, potential, gauss-law, integration

I'm having trouble finding the potential inside an insulated sphere by setting the potential at the center of the sphere to 0 and then integrating from there.

I know that if I set the reference voltage to infinity, then the potential outside the sphere is $kQ/r$ and the potential inside is $(kQ/R) * (3-r^2/R^2)$. However, how would I find the potential integrating from the center of the sphere instead of infinity. Right now I'm not sure how to set up that integral.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integrand is the same as for the case $V(\infty) =0$, you only have to change the first endpoint of the integral to $0$ instead of $\infty$:
$$V(x) = -\int_0^x \vec{E}\cdot d\vec{x}' $$

Answer (score 0):

Potential at center of the sphere is the potential of bringing the charges to surface of sphere added to the potential caused by the layers of the bulk of sphere. Hint : the key word here is layer of the bulk